# name 'WorksheetNotFound' is not defined

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-except, pygsheets

I'm trying to use try/except for error handling working with the pygsheets library. My code is as follows:

```
def export_col_values(workbook, df, columns):
    """for a list of columns, creates a new sheet for each column and exports unique values and their counts to that sheet"""
    for col in columns:
        value_counts = df[col].value_counts()
        counts_df = pd.DataFrame(value_counts).reset_index()
        counts_df['index'] = counts_df['index'].astype(str)
        try:
            worksheet = workbook.worksheet_by_title(col)
        except WorksheetNotFound:
            workbook.add_worksheet(col)
            worksheet = workbook.worksheet_by_title(col)
        worksheet.set_dataframe(counts_df, start='A1')
    print(f'{len(columns)} sets of column values exported.')
```

when the worksheet does not exist, i want to create a new worksheet. however, i get the error 'WorksheetNotFound' is not defined. i understand that I haven't defined the term WorksheetNotFound anywhere in my code, but my understanding was that the 'except' statement would catch any error of the 'WorksheetNotFound' type (this is the error I get when trying to access a worksheet that does not exist). Does try/except not work with all errors? Or are there only certain types of errors that an except statement recognizes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pygsheets.WorksheetNotFound ([doc](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#pygsheets.WorksheetNotFound)). so try

```
except pygsheets.WorksheetNotFound:
```